# unittest.mock: how to mock two calls on method?

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest.mock

How to i mock datetime.datetime.now with two calls on same method?

Below my tried:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def metodo():
    return dt.today().strftime('%Y'), dt.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X %z')


def test_metodo(self):
    expected = ('2018', "2018-12-14 12:34:56")
    mock_date = Mock(spec=mypackage.metodo)
    today.side_effect=list(expected)
    self.assertIsNotNone(metodo())
    self.assertEqual(expected, metodo())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have sucess with this.

```
@patch('mypackage.dt')
def test_metodo(self, mock_date):
    expected = ('2018', "2018-12-14 12:34:56")
    mock_date.today.return_value = mypackage.dt(2018, 12, 14, 12, 34, 56)
    mock_date.today.return_value.strftime.side_effect = list(expected)
    self.assertIsNotNone(metodo())
    self.assertEqual(expected, metodo())
```